# Reading an array of Json object inside String double quotes in hive column is returning null

Tags: json, hive, hql

Code below is returning null:

```
select get_json_object(events,'$.payload') 
from
(
select '{"payload":"[{"one":1}]"}' as events
) s
```

Code below is returning proper value:

```
select get_json_object(events,'$.payload') 
from
(
select '{"payload":[{"one":1}]}' as events
) s
```

The value of payload is a Json array object.When i am keeping these Json array object inside String double quotes({"payload":"[{"one":1}]"}), it is returning null.Please suggest how to retrieve when Json array is inside string.

Comment: In the first case the query asks for a json object but receives a string. I do not know the runtime, but it is definitely not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a Json object inside String, when i removed double quotes using regex, it worked:

select events,get_json_object(events,'$.payload') as col
from

(
select regexp_replace('{"payload":"[{"one":1}]}"','(?<=\:)"(?=\[)|(?<=\])"','') as events

) s